# margin property in a div of another div

Tags: html, css

html:

```
div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itro">
          <ul>
            <li>
            <h2> Title</h2>
            <p>This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content. </p>
           </il>
           <ul>

                <div id="logo"> <img src="image/bottom_logo.png" alt="logo" width="45" height="50" align="right">
                </div>

        </div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper
{
    width:850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #B3B3B3;

}
#itro
{
    width:550px;
    border: 6px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background:#E7E7E7;
    margin-top:70px; 
}
```

I want to set margin on #itro  but when I see it in browser div id="wrapper"> is also set top margin:70px;  why?

Comment: Probably because you have syntax errors everywhere...  Your wrapper div doesn't end.  Your UL doesn't end.  The ending LI is spelled IL...

Comment: depending on the browser, I have always found top and bottom margin to add extra margin to other elements around them.  Just add 70px of top padding to your wrapper div and you will achieve the same affect

Comment: That's a misleading comment about syntax errors everywhere.  There are only 3 syntax errors.  Try pointing them out instead of just being condescending. There is an opening `<` missing on the first div, and you have `</il>` instead of `</li>`.  You also have `<ul>` instead of `</ul>` on the closing unordered list tag.

Comment: Rephrase:  There are 5 syntax errors.  Your missing a `/` right before the closing `>` for the img tag, and there is a `</div> missing.

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
#wrapper{
    width:850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #B3B3B3;
    height:500px;
}
#itro
{
    width:550px;
    border: 6px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background:#E7E7E7;
    margin-top:70px; 
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itro">
          <ul>
            <li>
            <h2> Title</h2>
            <p>This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content.This is dumy content. </p>
           </li>
           </ul>
            <div> <img src="image/bottom_logo.png" alt="logo" width="45" height="50" align="right" /></div>

      </div>

        </div>
```

some tags were with their typing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Set your position on absolute for the wrapper and add a `height`. In my case I used auto but this could be any value.

see the fiddle [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/sU69r/3/)